# show product base on browser url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I want to show product dynamic base on browser link. For example if
`http://www.example.com?product=[data.productList.id]` then show `data.productList.text`

Expected results: if http://www.example.com?product=62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d then show **Product 001**.

I have tried many method.

My js is below :

```
const browserId = data.productList.id

if (window.location.href.contains('?product=' + browserId) > -1) {
    $('.test').append(productItemName(data.productList.id))
}
function productItemName(productName) {
    return data.productList.filter(product => product.id === productName)?.[0]?.id;
}
```

my data js is below:

```
var data = {
    productList: [
    {
        id: "62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d",
        link: "javascript:void(0)",
        imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000001_12032019.png",
        text: 'Product 001',
        price: '368.00',
        hitRate: '45472',
        goldMedal: false,
        newItem: true,
        newShop: true,
        freeDelivery: true,
        ShopId: '5cfb048c-86e8-4d2d-85bf-e4e9e1effdcb'
        },
        {
        id: "4a074028-d72a-4954-a159-f41adeb5cc5b",
        link: "javascript:void(0)",
        imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000002_12032019.png",
        text: 'Product 002',
        price: '99.00',
        hitRate: '25241',
        goldMedal: true,
        newItem: false,
        newShop: true,
        freeDelivery: true,
        ShopId: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26'
        }]
}
```

html is below:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get value which is under `product` using `searchParams.get("product");` and then pass same to your function to get required text.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your json  data
var data = {
  productList: [{
      id: "62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d",
      link: "javascript:void(0)",
      imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000001_12032019.png",
      text: 'Product 001',
      price: '368.00',
      hitRate: '45472',
      goldMedal: false,
      newItem: true,
      newShop: true,
      freeDelivery: true,
      ShopId: '5cfb048c-86e8-4d2d-85bf-e4e9e1effdcb'
    },
    {
      id: "4a074028-d72a-4954-a159-f41adeb5cc5b",
      link: "javascript:void(0)",
      imgurl: "/img/upload/png/joyacart_000002_12032019.png",
      text: 'Product 002',
      price: '99.00',
      hitRate: '25241',
      goldMedal: true,
      newItem: false,
      newShop: true,
      freeDelivery: true,
      ShopId: '10eb4250-47d6-41ad-a429-f65e05836f26'
    }
  ]
}
//your url
var url_string = "http://www.example.com?product=62276197-6059-4c21-9b40-c5b1d277e85d";
var url = new URL(url_string);
//get product parameter value
var browserId = url.searchParams.get("product");
//checking if id is not null
if (browserId != null) {
  //pass id
  $('.test').append(productItemName(browserId))
}

function productItemName(productName) {
  return data.productList.filter(product => product.id === productName)?.[0]?.text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: hi, the url_string, is hard code if i change to another product id will won't work

Comment: Yes for demo I have harded coded that ..you just need to get your url like `var url      = window.location.href;` and everything else will be same.Try like that let me know if you face any error.

Answer (score 0):

at my webconsole `productItemName` function errors me with bad syntax (meaning this `?.[0]?.text`)

try this

```
function productItemName(productName) {
    let result = data.productList.find((item) => item.id === productName);
    return result !== undefined ? result.text : "Not Found";
}
```